# WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD multiple messages

Tags: c#, windows, monitoring, clipboard

I'm working on a small clipboard manager which should remember recent copied text. I'm using Windows system messages for being notified when something has been copied to clipboard by WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD. The problem is some of the applications I use send multiple WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD messages to my application, for instance when I copy something in Chrome web browser it's only one message, miranda's chat window sends 3 of the same messages with the same text to the clipboard viewer's chain. How to avoid this ?

Answer (score 2):

Some applications put different versions of the same text on the clipboard (RTF,Unicode,ASCII) Could this be the reason?

Comment: I think it is. Even so, hwo to avoid this ? By saving clipboard change time and then if the change between now is really low, not to show it in history ? To keep only one copy in certain format ?

Comment: There is no need to fetch all the different types, since the clipboard internally converts between them when fetched. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649013(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Synthesized_Clipboard_Formats